# sass array with @for?

Tags: css, arrays, sass

I would like make a array with a loop in sass, but i don't know is possible.
There is my expected output:

```
$light: #fff;
$gray: (
    darken($light, 1%),
    darken($light, 2%),
    darken($light, 3%),
    darken($light, 4%),
    darken($light, 5%),
    darken($light, 6%),
    darken($light, 7%),
    darken($light, 8%)
);
```

And this is my actual code:

```
$light: #fff;
$gray: (
    @for $i from 1 through 8 {
        darken($light, $i%),
    }
);
```

P.S. This not working.

Comment: The output must be CSS file not another SASS file.

Comment: I want only variables. Look at Black Enigma aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping in the list.
Create a **list** `$gray`.
Inside a loop, **append** the colours to the `$gray` list.

```
$light: #fff;
$gray: ();

@for $i from 1 through 8 {
  $gray: append($gray, darken($light, $i) );
}
```

`$gray` now holds 8 different colours

```
div {
   /* Access the entire list or array */
   color: $gray;
}

p {
  /* Access individual item from list or array */
  color: nth($gray, 5) /* where 5 is the index. Indexes start from 1 and NOT 0 */
}
```

compiles to the following css

```
div {
  color: #fcfcfc #fafafa #f7f7f7 whitesmoke #f2f2f2 #f0f0f0 #ededed #ebebeb; }

p {
  color: #f2f2f2; }
```